# php : simple azure login with info

Tags: php, azure, authentication, single-sign-on

Hi have an application written in PHP using MySQL as database backend and I want to use a login authentication from my AD azure.

I have found several files examples searching with google but they are too complex for my needs.

So, I have a link like this: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=$myidclient&redirect_uri=$mydirapp&response_type=code`

After unsuccessful login ,  i am redirect to  `/mydirapp/index.php` with an **http GET** value named **code**

My problem : (in my file index.php) I want to get
- the `email address` used to this authentication
- the `firstname` and `lastname` of this user

I have understand that I need a token from this GET value named 'code'
and by this token, I can ask my AD.

Comment: Hi @kadel, do you have any update now?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand very clearly, about your **unsuccessful login**. Actually, Azure AD implement with OAuth 2.0 grand flow to authenticate and authorize your users.

And the url you provided is the first step to generate the authentication code, then you direct your user to this endpoint, any unsuccessfully authentication occurs, it will not redirect to your uri. The error message will be shown to your user in the IDP page.

If your user has redirected to your uri with the code parameter, it means that this user has successfully signed on in Azure AD.

After authentication, your user need to set the `access_token` in `Authorization` request header to your server. If you want to get the info of authenticated user, you can try to use following code snippet:

```
$headers = getallheaders();
$token = (explode(' ',$headers['Authorization']))[1];
list($headb64, $bodyb64, $cryptob64) = explode('.',$token);
$payload = json_decode(base64_decode($bodyb64));

echo $payload->{'family_name'};
echo $payload->{'given_name'};
echo $payload->{'upn'}; //email
```

You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-authentication-scenarios?toc=%2fazure%2factive-directory%2fdevelop%2ftoc.json#claims-in-azure-ad-security-tokens for the supported claim in payload.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.